# &-ing two BitArrays in Julia?

Tags: julia

Using Julia 1.5.3 and Julia 1.6.0 neither versions seems to support & for BitArrays.

I have two BitArrays like for instance

```
x = BitArray([1,0,1])
```

and

```
y=BitArray([0,0,1])
```

and wish to intersect them to find:

```
x&y=BitArray([0,0,1])
```

but the operator & does not seem to support BitArrays and using .* seems to be very time consuming.

Does anyone know a good method for finding the intersection of two bit arrays in Julia?

Answer (score 10):

`&` works for scalar values, while you are applying them to arrays. When applying scalar operators (or functions) to an array, you should use 'broadcasting', which you can do by adding a dot to the operator:

```
jl> x .& y
3-element BitVector:
 0
 0
 1
```

BTW, I cannot see any timing difference between `.*` and `.&`. In fact it seems that `*` just calls `&`.

What sort of performance are you seeing?

```
jl> using BenchmarkTools

jl> @btime $x .* $y;
  48.479 ns (2 allocations: 128 bytes)

jl> @btime $x .& $y;
  48.426 ns (2 allocations: 128 bytes)
```